# Set default UV Image Editor display mode

Tags: uv-image-editor

Is there a way to change the default display of the UV editor? What I mean is when I split the screen and go to UV/Image Editor the Render Result is the default display mode, and I have to click the X to get to the blank image:

[image]

After x-ing out:

[image]

I would like to set the default display mode to be a new, blank image. Possible?

Comment: You could try open new file, clear that Render Result in UV / Image editor window and save user prefs.

Comment: This worked perfectly and made complete sense after I read it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open new file, clear that Render Result in the [UV / Image editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/introduction.html) window and [save User Prefences](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/introduction.html#save-user-settings). Note that the latter will overwrite previously saved settings so you might want to backup them first.